# Size limitation on Facebook App Id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

Is there a size limitation on Facebook App Id? How many characters will this usually be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed size for any ID or Token in Facebook.

[Click here for source quoted bellow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2)

> Object IDs
>
> Each node has a unique ID which is used to access it via the Graph API. **We specifically do not document any node/object ID structure or format because it is extremely likely to change over time and apps should not make assumptions based on current structure.**

This extends to access tokens as well.